# Binary array search in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I can't seem to get this code to work right. If they key is in the array the code should alert True and if it's not in the array it should alert false. I can't seem to get it right. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Search</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction() {
        var list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
        var key = 9;
        var result1 = 0;
        //var result2 = 0;
        result1 = search(list, key);

    }
    function search(list, key) {
        var left = 0;
        var right = list.length - 1;
        while (left <= right) {
            var mid = left + ((right - left) >>> 1);
            var cmp = key - list[mid];
            if (cmp > 0 ){
                left = alert("True");
            } else if (cmp < 0){
                alert("False");
            }else {
                return mid;
            }
                return mid;
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<h1>Search:</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="testFunction()">Volume</button>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `>>>` isn't correct...just use `>`

Comment: Why not just do `list.indexOf(key)`?

Comment: Yeah, this seems too complex for what you're trying to do. Just do `return list.indexOf(key)!==-1` in the search function, and nothing else

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ..because a unarysearch is boring. (But maybe it's for a very large array, or maybe it's for a school assignment, or just to learn..)

Comment: Anyway, I'd recommend finding an existing binary search implementation (of which there are many, see Wikipedia) and slowly analyze it compared with the current implementation. *Use the Debugger* to inspect the boundary changes and comparison values.

Comment: you code will work if input is sorted,  you want it to work like that or not?

Comment: @hitman4890 The current input is sorted.

Comment: can you tell me what do you want from this variable :  var cmp = key - list[mid]; and : var mid = left + ((right - left) >>> 1);

Comment: @ToonDinDarkDevil That's not the problem. The problem is not correctly handling the advancing. Again, *use the Debugger* to aide troubleshooting.

Comment: This is what I am working on:

Write a JavaScript function named search that takes two parameters: an array named list and a number named key. The function must determine if key is stored in list. Your code should return true if the number is stored in the array and should return false otherwise. Use this function header for the function:
function search(list, key) {

Answer (score 1):

There are very few cases when you'd see an advantage of doing this instead of `.indexOf`, for example, if you meet these two conditions

1. Your data is ordered
2. You wish to go on to extend this to use a comparator

Now, you didn't seem to be moving your mid point but just returning it, instead try something like

```
function search(haystack, needle, i, j) {
    var k;
    if (i !== 0 && !i) i = 0;
    if (j !== 0 && !j) j = haystack.length - 1;
    if (needle < haystack[i] || haystack[j] < needle) return false;
    if (i === j) return haystack[i] === needle;
    while (i < j) {
        k = Math.floor(i + (j - i) / 2);
        if (haystack[k] === needle) return true;
        if (haystack[k] < needle) i = k + 1;
        else j = k - 1;
    }
    return (i === j) && (haystack[i] === needle);
}
```

So you have

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

search(arr, 0); // false
search(arr, 1); // true
search(arr, 2); // true
search(arr, 3); // true
search(arr, 4); // true
search(arr, 5); // true
search(arr, 6); // false
```

---

> Write a JavaScript function named search that takes two parameters: an array named list and a number named key. The function must determine if key is stored in list. Your code should return true if the number is stored in the array and should return false otherwise.

```
function search(list, key) {
    return list.indexOf(key) !== -1;
}
```

In an ECMAScript 6 environment you could write a comparator version of this using [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
function search(list, key) {
    return list.findIndex(e => e === key) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 you're right, _only_ was too exclusive. I've re-worded it thanks!

Comment: edit to move `i === j` test out of the loop, test was done `2 * iterations` (`===` in loop and `<=` in condition), now is just `iterations + 2`

Comment: As you can see I'm a noob I am trying to understand your code. Here is what I am working on:

Write a JavaScript function named search that takes two parameters: an array named list and a number named key. The function must determine if key is stored in list. Your code should return true if the number is stored in the array and should return false otherwise. Use this function header for the function:
function search(list, key) {

Comment: @user5500799 I've edited in a function to meet what you just described. The function in my original answer is similar (the `i` and `j` args are optional, you could remove them as parameters and re-write the first 3 lines to `var`). I just call the _list_ `haystack` and the _key_ `needle` (_key_ is a really bad identifier name for what is meant here). It first tests "is the `needle` between the end points `i..j`?", then it tests "is the middle point (`k`) `needle`?", if not, it moves the relevant end point next to the mid-point we just tested and repeats until we run out of positions to test

Comment: Dang I really need to apply myself more in this, you made that code look so simple compared to how I was trying to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

may be you can try this binary search function

```
function binarySearch(array, key) {
    var lo = 0,
        hi = array.length - 1,
        mid,
        element;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = ((lo + hi) >> 1);
        element = array[mid];
        if (element < key) {
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (element > key) {
            hi = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks similar to what I was trying to do, how can I get it to alert true or false? True if the key is found and false if it is not?

Comment: var result =  binarySearch(array, key); if(result >= 0) {alert("True");} else {alert("False");}